# How can I change the position of the Country and the Postal code for email PDF invoices?

Tags: magento-1.8, email, invoice, pdf, address

I would like to change the position of "country" with "zip code"?
Everything else is correct.

You can see the Value:

> Zürich, **8605**

and

> **Schweiz**

Those need to be changed, but where can I do this?

[image]

Comment: add a screenshot :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check the admin:

System > Configuration > Customer Configuration > Address Templates

You'll see various options (Text, HTML, PDF).

You can change the formatting/order of the PDF addresses at the 'PDF' option:

```
{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}|
{{depend company}}{{var company}}|{{/depend}}
{{if street1}}{{var street1}}
{{/if}}
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}|{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}|{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}|{{/depend}}
{{if city}}{{var city}},|{{/if}}
{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}|
{{var country}}|
{{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}|
{{depend fax}}<br/>F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}|
{{depend vat_id}}<br/>VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}|
```

You can move `{{var country}}` to the desired location.